# New computer WindowsXP on Server 2003 network will not connect to file server

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, windows-xp

When we try to connect to our file server with the new computer, it denies access. The computer is joined to the domain and I can see it on active directory. We need to connect to the file server for printing and terminal services. We have had this happen before and found that reinstalling Windows will fix the problem but I would like a speedier solution. any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you be more specific about how you're logging-on to the PC and what kind of error messages you're receiving.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check firewall settings?  I seem to have this problem every time I set up a Windows server.  There are so many arbitrary settings for users and authentication, it's easy to lose track of it all.  Also, on some Windows installs or virus security centers Windows file sharing is disabled by default.  For example, by going to My Computer -> Properties -> Computer Name and running the Wizard, you can enable file-sharing, which for some reason has helped me get connected in the past.  Even though file-sharing (in theory) shouldn't need to be enabled on the client side.